# Page jumps when fadeIn() and fadeOut() of two overlapping elements occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created something in jQuery, I have a problem when clicking the images though. If you scroll down entirely to the bottom of the page and then click, you'll see it jumps. I've tried multiple methods to prevent jumping but its not working.

Here is my code:

```
$('.author').click(function(e) {
    var name = $(this).attr('id') + '-info';

    $('.author-info article').hide();
    $('#' + name).fadeIn();

    $('.author').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

here is the live link - http://sites.lukespoor.com/author/

any help is appreciated

Comment: Why bother wrapping the images in links that have no href? Apply the click event to the images. It's your `javascript:;` in the `<a>` that's causing this.

Answer (score 4):

It is jumping because, when the first element fades out the height of the page changes. So, it scrolls to the bottom of the page. You cannot fix it with `e.preventDefault`.

Set a fixed height for the parent element.

```
.author-info {height:200px;}
```

fixes the problem.

Another solution will be

```
.author-info {position:relative;}
.author-info article {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;opacity:0;}
```

Instead of using `.fadeIn` set the opacity to 1 and instead of `.fadeOut` set the opacity to 0. You can use CSS transition or `.animate` for the fade effect.

Comment: @LukeSpoor - I'm guessing that `min-height` or some transition effect might work better. This is the problem, but you're triggering either an `overflow` or scrollbars.

Comment: If the div height is dynamic, it might be better to set the parent height on document load. Or you could stack the division using position absolute and use opacity to hide / show the divisions.

Comment: @LukeSpoor Sometimes silly mistakes can cause huge headaches. I too once spent a lot of time trying to fix the same issue. Initially blamed everything on jQuery before realizing that the problem was actually between the keyboard and the chair :)